# Can Spring DAO be merged into Service layer?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, dao, mybatis

I'm developing a web application with spring framework and mybatis.

In most cases(at least for me), DAO's methods are very short something like this:

```
public class UserDaoImpl extends SqlSessionDaoSupport implements UserDao {
  public User getUser(String userId) {
    return (User) getSqlSession().selectOne("org.mybatis.spring.sample.mapper.UserMapper.getUser", userId);
  }
}
```

So basically, I need to write a method(e.g. `getUser(String userId)`) in DAO for each query which is being forwarded to service objects where it is being used. It seems unnecessarally redundunt to me.

My co-worker is trying to make it simple. He wrote `CommonDao` like this:

```
@Repository
public class CommonDao {
    @Autowired
    private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSession;

    public Object insert(String queryId, Object params) {
        return sqlSession.insert(queryId, params);
    }

    public Object update(String queryId, Object params) {
        return sqlSession.update(queryId, params);
    }

    public Object delete(String queryId, Object params) {
        return sqlSession.delete(queryId, params);
    }

    public Object selectOne(String queryId) {
        return sqlSession.selectOne(queryId);
    }

    public Object selectOne(String queryId, Object params) {
        return sqlSession.selectOne(queryId, params);
    }
}
```

So we can use these methods in services like:

```
@Service
public class CrudService {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private CommonDao commonDao;
    ...

    public UserDto selectUser(Integer userId) {
        ...
        UserDto userDto = (UserDto) commonDao.selectOne("org.mybatis.spring.sample.mapper.UserMapper.getUser", userId);
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm kinda like this approch since it makes codes simpler. But I'm not sure it is a good prectice to follow.

Comment: it's not, use generics, will help out a lot. just think of time when u refactor naming of one of those classes, you would need to find all names writen like this and change them manually.

Comment: also, look at Spring data, in particular -> repositories. will save you lots of CRUD typing

Comment: ps: returning objects is bad practice. what are you going to do with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a boilerplate code and at the same time have type safety and leave your service layer free from DAO implementation details use [spring-mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/) [`MapperScannerConfigurer`](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/apidocs/reference/org/mybatis/spring/mapper/MapperScannerConfigurer.html).

In this case you can replace your DAOs with type-safe mappers.

The equivalent of your DAO

```
public class UserDaoImpl extends SqlSessionDaoSupport implements UserDao {
  public User getUser(String userId) {
    return (User)getSqlSession().selectOne(
        "org.mybatis.spring.sample.mapper.UserMapper.getUser", userId);
  }
}
```

will be this mapper class

```
package org.mybatis.spring.sample.mapper;

interface UserMapper {
  User getUser(String userId);
}
```

If you rename it to `UserDao` you will not need to change your services at all. Service only depends on the declared mapper interface.

Note that you need to define this interface in order to have type safety and also define the dependency of you service.

Of course you need configure `spring-mybatis` so that it generates mapper implementation based on the mapper interfaces defined in your code. This is rather straightforward and there are [many options](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/mappers.html#scan) how to do that.

Comment: Can `getUser` method be body-less in `UserMapper`?

Comment: That was a typo that I have fixed. It should be interface of cause.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what you are struggling with, is normal in MyBatis.

Your co-worker pointed you in some direction... But what is the real value of `CommonDao` in this shape? For me it's not very useful. You still need almost the same amount of code - and still you have to do a lot of casting.

As @Rom Konoval said, there is `MapperScannerConfigurer` which can generate mapper implementations - this way you don't write redundant implementations and have the benefit of a type safety - type casting still happens but is hidden from you. You can try it.
Here is a [sample usage](https://github.com/mybatis/jpetstore-6) on the GitHub.

Alternatively, you can create DAO implementations by yourself (as you already did) or just use the `SqlSessionTemplate` directly in your Services. Up to you. Just keep your code base as small as possible and follow a common sense.

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me a way to "talk to your database in the Service layer directly"? What I'm thinking is using `SqlSessionTemplate` in services instead of DAO, but that still would use generics.

Comment: Just to explain about "You still need almost the same amount of code" - There could be multiple select queries. And as I said, I need to write a method for each query. By using `CommonDao`, I only need to write one method(e.g. `selectOne`) to use select queries. So, the amount of code is decreased. It is a bad practice to follow though.