# springboot+mybatis, About Native Dao development

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, mybatis

I'm trying a new development method.
In mybatis3, I write mapper.java and mapper.xml usually.
I know, the sql statements is corresponded by sqlId(namespace+id).
I want to execute the sql statement like this :

```
SqlSession sqlSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
return sqlSession.selectList(sqlId, param);
```

but I get a error:

```
Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for mapper.JinBoot.test
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:150)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
    at cn.tianyustudio.jinboot.dao.BaseDao.select(BaseDao.java:20)
    at cn.tianyustudio.jinboot.service.BaseService.select(BaseService.java:10)
    at cn.tianyustudio.jinboot.controller.BaseController.test(BaseController.java:21)
```

here is my BaseDao.java

```
public class BaseDao {

  private static SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();

  public static List<Map> select(String sqlId, Map param) {
      try {
        factoryBean.setDataSource(new DruidDataSource());
        SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = factoryBean.getObject();
        SqlSession sqlSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
        return sqlSession.selectList(sqlId, param);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
  }
}
```

here is UserMapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="mapper.JinBoot">

    <select id="test" parameterType="hashMap" resultType="hashMap">
        select * from user
    </select>
</mapper>
```

the application.properties

```
mybatis.mapperLocations=classpath:mapper/*.xml
```

I start the project, the send a http request, after controller and service ,the param 'sqlId' in BaseDao is 'mapper.JinBoot.test' (see error info).

In method 'BaseDao.select', both the parameter and the result type is Map.

So I don't want to create UserMapper.java, I want try it.

How can I resolve it? What's the malpractice of this way？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work because spring boot creates its own `SqlSessionFactory`. And the option in `application.properties` that specifies where mappers should be looked for is only set for that `SqlSessionFactory`. You are creating unrelated session factory in your DAO and it does not know where to load mappers definition.

If you want to make it work you need that you DAO is spring managed so that you can inject mybatis session factory into it and use it in `select`. This would also require that you convert `select` into non static method.

As I understand you want to have only one method in you base DAO class and use it in individual specific DAO classes. I would say it makes little sense. If the method returns `Map` there will be some place that actually maps this generic type to some application specific types. This would probably be in the child DAOs. So you still need to create the API of the child DAO with the signature that uses some input parameters and returns some domain objects. And that's exactly what you want to avoid by not creating mybatis mapper classes.

The thing is that you can treat your mytabis mappers as DAOs. That is you mappers would be your DAOs. And you don't need another layer. As I understand now you have two separate layers - DAO and mappers and you want to remove boilerplate code. I think it is better to remove DAO classes. They are real boilerplate and mybatis mapper can serve as DAO perfectly. You inject it directly to you service and service depends only on the mapper class. The logic of the mapping is in the mapper xml file. See also answer to this question [Can Spring DAO be merged into Service layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560507/can-spring-dao-be-merged-into-service-layer/38571710#38571710)

Comment: I totally agree with you. In fact, my purpose is not to write service, it is just a experiment. For some very small project, If data security is not considered, service layer isn't necessary. The project only need one controller and one dao. Here is my experimental result. https://github.com/15050050972/JinBoot